# Sony MDR-XB650BT wireless headphones not charging

Tags: bluetooth, battery, headphones, bluetooth-speaker

I recently bought Sony MDR-XB650BT wireless headphones which can only be charged via USB cable connected to a computer. I haven't checked it in advance because I did not think that this can matter, but on the Sony website they state that only Windows and Mac computers are supported.

So my question is: can I somehow trick the headphones into thinking that they are connected to a Windows PC/Mac or should I just send them back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel really stupid now after two hour googling, but actually a simple reset of the headphones was sufficient. The headphones charge and work as expected.